# How do I get a json node value from json string using json path?

Tags: json, jsonpath, ready-api

Below is my **JSON** file

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "age": 1000000,
      "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
      "powers": [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And JSON path to retrieve all members name is - $.members[*].name

I am using Ready API and Groovy script to read this json using the path mentioned above, but I am encountering an Error message which says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.minidev.json.JSONValue` when I execute the below piece of code

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.*

Object dataObject = JsonPath.parse(jsonmentionedabove).read(
'$.members[*].name')
```

I have the following `jars` inside my Ready API lib & ext folders and have java version - 9.0.1 on my PC

```
json-path-2.4.0, json-smart-2.3
```

Could you please let me know on what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ready API or the json-path and json-smart libraries, but with pure groovy you can just do:

```
import groovy.json.*

def str  = """<the json string in your question>"""
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)
def memberNames = json.members*.name

println memberNames.join(", ")
```

which when executed will print:

```
Molecule Man, Madame Uppercut, Eternal Flame
```

JsonSlurper returns a java.util.Map of maps structure which can be navigated using normal groovy `findAll`, `collect`, etc operations or the [spead operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) (`*.`) as in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Placing asm-1.0.2.jar file in Ready API lib folder resolved the issue.